# Setting Ads width inside listview (Android)

Tags: android, listview, admob

i am creating a view as a listitem in a listview to hold an ads
but logcat error below
W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x150 dp, but only has 328x150 dp.
how can i precisely calculate 328 of my view?
it is actually the width of my listitem.

i cannot use smart banner because i am using an AdView object
thank you

Comment: Do not give any padding and margin with the listview item. Ads need whole width.

Comment: the ads is in the middle of listview, it will be ugly if no padding and margin. if i can get the width(328 here) generically, it is done. thank you

Comment: Then you have to make custom Ad in AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
`AdSize adSize = new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, AdSize.AUTO_HEIGHT);`

It will set the ad to the full width of listview item

Comment: thanks. but this was the exact error i got when i do like that : <